# JavaFX StringProperty.isEmpty

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm working on a project. Stuck on this part and do not understand what is wrong.
The method should work so that when there is no value then the alert will pop out, otherwise, the program will just keep running.

```
   public boolean NotEmpty() {
        if (first_nameProperty().get().isEmpty() || last_nameProperty().get().isEmpty() ||
                birthdateProperty().get().isEmpty() || emailProperty().get().isEmpty() || adressProperty().get().isEmpty()) {

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Validate Fields");
            alert.setContentText("Please Enter Into the Fields ");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.showAndWait();

            return false;

        }

        return true;

    }
```

And the Button function

```
 Button button = new Button("Add");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {

            if( ui.NotEmpty() == false) {
                list.add(
                        new UserInfo(
                                first_name.getText(),
                                last_name.getText(),
                                Integer.parseInt(age.getText()),
                                birthdate.getEditor().getText(),
                                email.getText(),
                                adress.getText()
                        )
```

Comment: Looks okay. I think you made a silly error in connecting the `fxml` file with your controller. I can't tell anything right now. If you share your code (e.g. github), maybe we can find the problem.

Comment: NotEmpty() returns false when one or more fields are empty. Does that really match with the condition in your button-action?

Comment: Some unrelated notes: (1) Methods names, according to Java naming conventions, start with a lower case letter—it should be `notEmpty()`; (2) Consider using `!ui.notEmpty()` instead of `ui.notEmpty() == false`.

Comment: As for your question, what exactly is wrong? What behavior are you seeing that tells you something is wrong? Please create a [mre] demonstrating the problem, then add it to your question via an [edit]. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: The problem is that when the if statement occurs, it proceeds to list.add
The program should stop before list.add
And when I use else than it works but now the problem is that list.add does not occur. Hope you understand, know that this is a poor explanation

Comment: Personally, I can't see the cause of the problem from the code you've provided. Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] (← read the linked page) that demonstrates said problem.